# Sheet Modal alert triggered from other class than ViewController Cocoa Mac Storyboard Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a simple project with a storyboard for a Mac OS X app. I placed a button on the NSView and created a new class called OtherClass. Then I linked an IBAction to the OtherClass.h. Now I want to make appear a model sheet in the main window. When using ViewController as class I could simply do:

```
NSWindow *window = [self.view window];
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc]init];
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:nil];
```

But how do I do this from another class? I am using Xcode 6.3 if this is important.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply refer the window object associated to button.
So you can call like this from your OtherClass

```
-(IBAction)callSheet:(id)sender {

       NSWindow *window;
if([sender respondsToSelector(@selector(window))]){

 window = [sender window];

     }else if([sender respondsToSelector(@selector(view))]){

    window = [sender view].window; 

    }

 //Now call your alert

    }
```

Comment: Thank you this works great with the button. I tried using the same method with a toolbar item as an IBAction button. But then the app crashes: [NSToolbarItem window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000120500

Comment: You can call like this for toolbar item : ToolbarItem.view.window

Comment: thanks for your answer but what do you suggest exactly? What is toolbar item for you? is it an IBOutlet of the toolbar item? I tried this without luck: NSWindow *window = [sender ToolbarItem.view.window] where ToolbarItem is iboutlet of the toolbar item in question

Comment: You can check the type of sender in your function and call the appropriate method. I modified the answer.Please check.

Comment: Hi sheen thanks for your time. So I use storyboard and added the toolbar to the window controller. I linked a toolbar item to AppDelegate as IBAction and added your code. NSAlert *notFound = [[NSAlert alloc]init]; NSWindow *window = [sender view].window; [notFound beginSheetModalForWindow:window  completionHandler:nil]; I can press the button without seeing the app crashing but no sheet appears.